# Согласование времен, речевые ошибки

Tags: времена

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, возможно ли подобное согласование времен (отрывок из стихотворения):

Под серым мрачным небосводом \ 
Надменный как-то шёл мудрец. \
И был он в статусе особом: \
Шептал кто лжец, а кто подлец \

Царю на ухо, между прочим. \
Да и всем советы он давал. \
Царь уважал его уж очень, \
Нередко другом называл.

Идёт мыслитель, громко молвит, \
Как надо жить он учит всех. \
А местный люд за старцем вторит, \
Считает чуть ли не за грех \

Не подойти, не поклониться, \
Не выслушав совет, уйти. \
Иначе будешь ты страшиться, \
Чтоб по башке не огрести. \

Ведь это глупых трусов стая! \
Кто властен - тот их рулевой. \
Они несутся, с ног сшибая \
Инакомыслящих долой. \
Ну и т.д.

В первых двух четверостишьях - прошедшее время, далее - настоящее. Можно ли так? И, конечно, если есть речевые ошибки или еще какие-нибудь, то просьба указать. Заранее спасибо:)

Comment: Почитал про согласование времен, вроде можно. Да и ошибку ещё нашел: нарушение ритма на слове "да" во втором четверостишьи.

Answer (score 1):

С временами терпимо, вполне корректно, но само стихотворение требует доработки.

Ошибки есть.

ПУНКТУАЦИОННЫЕ : Шептал (,)кто лжец, а кто подлец (,)

Царю на ухо (НЕТ ЗАПЯТОЙ) между прочим.

Как надо жить (,)он учит всех.

Стилистические:1)Иначе будешь ты страшиться, \ Чтоб по башке не огрести. - просторечие неуместно, нужно заменить нейтральными словами.2)с ног сшибая - просторечие. Может, сбивая?

Содержание:Ведь это глупых трусов стая! (неудачная метафора, стаи глупыми не бывают, они организованны и ведомы умным вожаком.Стадо -  ещё куда ни шло)

Кто властен - тот их рулевой.В стае вожак, а не рулевой, это ж не корабль. Уж взял метафору - рисуй картинку с ней, а всё в кучу не надо.

Речевая:  Они несутся, с ног сшибая / Инакомыслящих долой. (долой гонят, но не сшибают)